# Android Page Curl Animation

Tags: android, animation, flip

I'm bit new to android animations. Currently I'm developing an story activity which needs to use page curl animation like in iphones. As I found there is a way to do that in iphone. But still i couldn't find a way to do in android. so please help me on this.

Thanks to you all

Comment: There is no way of automatically doing this in Android, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 4):

There is a project in google code that solves that:
http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

Answer (score 1):

also, i've looked for good solutions and here is results of my researching:

- App in the Google play with curl animation:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader

- Project on the Github (both are used to images only):

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl

- Topics:

[Page Curl Animation in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549348/page-curl-animation-in-android)

[Implement page curl on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912849/implement-page-curl-on-android)

[Android page Curl animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015586/android-page-curl-animation)