# Built in pagecurl animation in android like iphone?

Tags: android, animation, page-curl

i want to know is there any source code available for page curl animation  in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think any built in page animation available for scrolling web view. but same discussion is going on here [Android page Curl animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015586/android-page-curl-animation)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following project:  http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

Is this about what you're looking for?

Comment: it is only for two static images. but i wanted to have this animation for webview