# Page Curl Animation on Android with OpenGL-ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to achieve a nice 3D page curl animation in Android.  I read some articles and found that nice effect can be achieved by OpenGL-ES so I started to learn OpenGL-ES (I did some of tutorials of OpenGL-ES and am still continuing) but I found it too complex for me to achieve this functionality.  Also I got some examples which are available on StackOverflow and on the net, they work but I am not able to understand it, can someone guide me to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Would you like us to search for all OpenGL ES examples for  android on StackOverflow and explain them here in detail how and why they work? That's redicilous ;-) Please ask something specific like *I tried to accomplish that with this coude, but it behaves like that and I can't get I right. Could you give me a hint what I'm doing wrong or missunderstand please?*

Comment: Hello knickedi,my problem is to how to implement page curl animation in android.but I could not find good tutorial for it(from where to start).

Comment: I am trying to implement opengles in android (like making triangles,rectangle,applying shadow etc..).

Comment: Come on. It's your quest, not our. It doesn't matter what you want to have. If you don't even try and share your results so far noone will ever reply to your question. We're not here to do your job, we will help you get it done right...

Comment: I am not telling you to do my job,I am just asking if someone has good knowledge working with opengles in android,i tried to search(still searching) about this topic on net but could not find good tutorial about it.I just wanted to know if I want to achieve this functionality from where to start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the question comments I have an answer to this question.

YES, you can do that with OpenGL, BUT you need a deep understanding of math and graphics. This is a lot to learn, this will cost you at least a couple of weeks and it's definitely a hard path to go if you do it only because of this single animation (all of this applies if you don't take code which you probably won't understand and another human being put his whole effort into).

Nevertheless there might a ready to use implementation but unfortunately I can't present you one because I don't know if there's any out there.

**Update**

You callenged me, so I was eger to know whether there is something out there (because I saw that before and couldn't believe that there isn't a project out there which already does that for you).

And actually I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015586/android-page-curl-animation) which seems to address the very same issue. And yes, there's someone who published his results [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/). And I have to admit: *I looks awesome*. It's also a pure java implementation.

*But still*: Having some background knowledge about OpenGL would enhance your whole attitude as developer. I'm not saying it's a must because not every one will succeed in OpenGL programming because it's quite hard to learn and implies a lot of math. But I think it's worth it because you will gain some deep understanding of current and all future graphical interfaces.

Comment: At last you understand my point,Thank you very much for putting your knowledge,actually this is my main problem like from where to start and how to go 1.how will you put edit text into screen using opengles 2.how will you touch its corner so that it will be curlled 3.how will you put shades and other effects.Now i will try my best to get rid of it and implement a nice 3d page curl.Thanks once again

Comment: Here's the idea how I would start: First of all, long process called learning OpenGL ES (and actually the common openGL API). Second tring to find out how you can interact with the actual android drawing mechanisim so you can get those results , manipulate them and draw your modifications back to screen. You could establish amazing looking effects with OpenGL, but you will have to face the heavy math.

Comment: yes you are right it seems long and very heavy maths process, but i think i should go for its implementation.wish me best of my luck.:)

Comment: I certainly do! It's a very interesting topic and the insights you will gain will change your attitude to graphical interfaces dramatically ;-)

Comment: Yes true,but salute to people who have already achieve this functionality for which i am just thinking of.