# PageTurn effect using JQuery in Android

Tags: android, jquery, animation, page-flipping

Here i develop one story book application with Images in Android, and here my problem is i want to use jQuery page-turn effect on ImageView in Android.

or use any animation which looks like original page flipping or turning.

Please give some ideas and suggestions.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: refer this:_

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015586/android-page-curl-animation

Comment: if u need to use page curl effect than u need to use viewflipper in android.here http://blog.kerul.net/2011/07/viewflipper-examplea-simple-flashcard.html good example has been given about view flipper and u can check out this page curl project also http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/ for downloading this project's source file u need to use Tortoise SVN software
best of luck
Aamirkhan I.

Comment: if any answer help u, don't forget to accept it..

Answer (score 1):

Download this project and refer the code, this is a good example:-

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

Comment: It use canvas, i do not want to use canvas.

Comment: Then use this one:_
above one is good,that is real PageTurn effect, if u don't want that try to use this one.

http://marcbuils.blogspot.co.il/2011/09/flippage-tournez-les-pages-sur-votre.html

Answer (score 0):

OK so there is a plugin called [Turnjs](http://turnjs.com/) which cost money for developers, but seems to be a bit more established and one called [FlipPage](http://marcbuils.blogspot.co.il/2011/09/flippage-tournez-les-pages-sur-votre.html) which LGPL v3 (but the website is not in english).  The demo on the flippage site seems pretty good, so I would say it is a good starting off point.