# How to do curl page in android like as iPad application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In my application I am using map view and according application when ever we want change satellite view and normal view those settings in inside of curl page can any one help to how to do this one.Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3015586/1321873

Answer (score 0):

See http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

Answer (score 0):

The below location has a fantastic example of page curl.
This is based on opengl and is much better in terms of performance as compared to the other available solutions.
The code in the project is very well documented and can be modified easily to fit your requirements.

https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl